# Хранение статических данных

Tags: php, mysql

В игре есть разные "объекты", описаны они на php в виде ассоциативного массива:

```
$blds = array(
    1 => array(
        'name' => '...',
        'info' => '...'
        ...
    ),
    ...
);
```

Как правильней будет реализовать получение данных по "объекту":

1) "разложить объект" ($blds) по таблицам БД и брать значения из БД;

2) загружать (include, require) скрипт c описанным "объектом" ($blds), когда нужно.

Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: Если это одноразовая сущность, то храните ее в файле-конфиге.

Если это многократно появляющая сущность, то раскидывайте по полям БД.

Answer (score 1):

Для таких целей выбирайте файлы**** (если один файл = один объект, не будет других манипуляций, кроме как запросить полную информацию).